# Java : spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in a dependent project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have build two projects using Java

1. myproject-db -  for db interactions
2. myproject-api - for exposing api calls

myproject-db uses spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as a dependency and I am able to build and install it all fine.

myproject-api - is a spring boot project and it uses myproject-db as a dependency. When I run my myproject-api project it gives me error

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I have defined my dataSource url application.properties file in myproject-db like below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=somepass
```

application.properties file of myproject-api is empty.

Question is why am I getting this error.

Comment: I assume the main class is in myproject-api, and since application.properties is empty. No values are getting read. You can possibly copy those values from the db to api and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one delivery application configured with Spring Boot with dependent modules

You can have for example

```
myproject-parent
       |
    myproject-api
    myproject-ui
```

If your delivery project (main war/jar) is myproject-api then application.properties and `@Configuration` must be configured in `myproject-api` and in `@SpringBootApplication` scope

You cannot have two `@SpringBootApplication` scopes